# How to properly display HTML entities in the DOM

Tags: html

I have a JSON data feed, that consists of various HTML entities (i.e. ">"). I would like to display the feed in an HTML table (say via React) where these entities show up as plain text. What's the canonical way of processing the entities?

Comment: Your question is to broad, specifics with code in the form of a [mcve] would be much appreciated

Comment: In general, to render the string to be displayed as parsed html, make use of element.innerHTML property.
Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML for more details